# Spring : Calling same jsp page with 3 different controllers simultanously

Tags: spring, jsp, model-view-controller

I am trying to display 3 tables in the same jsp page.
Each table is handled by a distinct controller.(each controller adds an attribute(list) to  the Model).

so i have three controllers containing each one method with the : 
@RequestMapping(value="/index")

and each method returns: return "Display";

here is a method of one controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/index")
public String pageIndex(Model model)
{  Ods_Gis_Actel e= new Ods_Gis_Actel("555", "france", "75L","555");
    List<Ods_Gis_Actel> liste = new ArrayList<Ods_Gis_Actel>();
      liste.add(e);



    model.addAttribute("listeOds",liste);
    return "Display";
}
```

It seems that one jsp page cannot be called simultanously by different controllers (error 500), so how can i display different tables in the same jsp page simultanously?

thanks;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have 3 controllers mapped to the same path. How would Spring know which one to call? Have one controller mapped to the path and dispatching to the JSP, and call 3 methods fom this controller, each method being responsible for one of the tables to display in the view:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/index")
public String pageIndex(Model model) {
    addFirstTableDataToModel(model);
    addSecondTableDataToModel(model);
    addThirdTableDataToModel(model);

    return "Display";
}

private void addFirstTableDataToModel(Model model) {
    Ods_Gis_Actel e= new Ods_Gis_Actel("555", "france", "75L","555");
    List<Ods_Gis_Actel> liste = new ArrayList<Ods_Gis_Actel>();
    liste.add(e);
    model.addAttribute("listeOds", liste);
}
```

Also, respect the Java naming conventions. Classes don't contain underscores.